# Detecting a change in a .NET collection or list

Tags: c#, .net

I have a class with properties and collections. It also has a property called `Dirty`. I want to set this `Dirty` flag if the state of an instance of this class changes in any way.

Obviously for the properties, I can just set this in the setter. However, I'm unsure of the best way of detecting a change in the collection. Whilst I could create my own collection class that derives from the .NET collection class and do it that way, I'm wondering if there's another way which doesn't require my own custom collection type?

**Update for clarification**

Just to clarify, I don't need to track in a nested way - I literally just want to know if items have been added/removed from the collection.

Comment: [ObservableCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) - not exact match, but maybe it will do?

Comment: fyi the observable collections only observe that the items (references) in the collection have changed, not the nested properties.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov that only looks at the items, not the properties with in.

Comment: "... which doesn't require my own custom collection type". Which collection type are you using right now and what would be acceptable replacements? Would any built-in type do?

Comment: @DanielA.White sure - was not clear if OP looking for all changes or just collection level changes... tracking changes is hard :)

Comment: Sounds like a perfect fit for BindingList<T>?

Comment: I'm currently using ICollection (instantiated as a List though). The object actually gets persisted to a database via Entity Framework Code First - so as long as it doesn't break that - then it's good. I'll check out ObservableCollection as this seems a good fit I think. I don't need to track the contents of items in the collection - just whether or not items have been added/removed from it.

Comment: Sounds like a tricky one. So you have a list of Collection of Custom Complex Type, and if any property of any of the item changes you want to track IsDirty.

Comment: Updated the description to clarify the confusion about my requirement :)

Comment: Thanks for the upvotes - note sure why it got that initial downvote! :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With your edit, [`ObservableCollection<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) would be an *excellent* choice. It implements [`INotifyCollectionChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), so it will raise an event whenever an item is added or removed.

Note that this class is used all the time in WPF for that exact purpose, so the *framework* can listen to that event and add/remove UI elements as necessary.

Answer (score 2):

See [`ObservableCollection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which contains the `CollectionChanged` event.

Be wary however that `ObservableCollection`s are *not* thread-safe, though there are several tutorials/articles/projects on how to implement such a thing